# Dropwizard/Jetty REST calls returning http status 202 under moderate-to-light load

Tags: java, rest, http, jetty, dropwizard

I'm running into an issue with a rest service built on dropwizard 0.7.1.3, which I believe has Jetty 0.9.7.1.v20131107 embedded.

The service has various REST endpoints setup, where some are used to submit a background task, some are used for checking status of said job, and lastly, some are used to retrieve the results of the job when it is completed. To be clear... none of these endpoints are explicitly returning 202.

I'm currently doing some load testing of the application where it is simulating multiple users hitting the service simultaneously in order to submit jobs, check their status and retrieve results. For a simulation of about 30 users ramped up over 30 seconds, there are about 3500 request submitted to the service over the course of a couple minutes. The average rate is about 16/second. During this time, I see the occasional return of 202 http status code from some of the endpoints. If I increase the number of users, the frequency of 202s increases as well.

During profiling of the application while load testing, the CPU and heap space available both seem to stay within reasonable bounds. The same goes for garbage collection. Also, the number of threads in use is much lower than the maximum set for the service which is about 1024... I see maybe 175 allocated.

I'm at a point now where I can't seem to figure out what is causing these 202s. I've tried increasing acceptor threads, selector threads, etc settings in drop wizard config but they don't help to alleviate the problem.

I've tried googling for information on what circumstances cause Jetty to return a 202 but I can't find any useful information on this either.

Has anyone experienced an issue such as this before? Can anyone tell me under what circumstances Jetty will decide to return a 202 versus actually process the request? and what I might be able to change in order to alleviate the problem?

It just doesn't make sense to me that an average rate of 16 requests/second would be enough to warrant returning 202. If there is any additional information that might help to diagnose this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we discovered that there actually was some code in an internal company library that was returning a 202 in a very specific case.

Answer (score 0):

**Note: this question is too unclear and I will flag it.** But my comment doesn't fit the requirement for size.

If you are **`absolutely sure`** that `Jetty` is to blame you could check for some weird configuration of Jetty [QoS](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/qos-filter.html) or [DoS](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/dos-filter.html) filters. Their default return codes are `HTTP 503 Service unavailable` but the return code is configurable.

IMO the return of `HTTP 202` status codes seems to be an intended behaviour from the application.
The official registry of HTTP status codes at `IANA` states:

> `202  Accepted`   [RFC7231, Section
> 6.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.3)
>
> The 202 response is intentionally noncommittal.  Its purpose is to
> allow a server to accept a request for some other process (perhaps a
> batch-oriented process that is only run once per day) without
> requiring that the user agent's connection to the server persist until
> the process is completed.  The representation sent with this response
> ought to describe the request's current status and point to (or embed)
> a status monitor that can provide the user with an estimate of when
> the request will be fulfilled.

As a batch-oriented process you can imagine for example the export of several GB of files to some web-server or S3-like object storage. The server accepted the request, instructed successfully the other systems that are involved in the process and tell you that the task is started. It can't provide the result immediately. When and where you can find the result is application dependent and have to be checked with it documentation.

Comment: I realize there are a lot of factors here, but basically what i was looking to find out is if anyone knew of a scenario that would cause Jetty to return a 202. I definitely don't have any certainty on whether Jetty is the problem here. My apologies if that was unclear. 

I actually posted the same question to the Jetty mailing list and i got an answer back from a developer on the list. They confirmed that there is nothing in Jetty that would be returning a 202. So the problem is definitely something else. Maybe dropwizard or other lib. I'll keep digging and respond to this when i know more.

Comment: You **should** start your digging with checking the documentation of the application and talking with the development team - what are the conditions that trigger the return of `HTTP 202` status code from the application endpoints. Next verify how many `background tasks` of the submitted type your test environment can handle. This is not unlimited number. If you hit this number when load testing the application this is the problem. It's too early for saying the problem is this or that library.